# postgreSQL dump and restore partitioned table (w/ insert trigger) from one server to another

Tags: postgresql

Trying to dump a partitioned table from one server to another in PostgreSQL (9.4.5).  Fairly new to postgres, and inherited the project, please let me know if more background info is needed.

```
dbname=> SELECT COUNT (id) FROM parent_table_to_copy;
count  
--------
499992
(1 row)
```

`parent_table_to_copy` has a trigger:

```
parent_table_to_copy_trigger BEFORE INSERT ON parent_table_to_copy FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE parent_table_to_copy_function()
```

Maybe not important, but the function is a series of `ELSIF`'s that partition `parent_table_to_copy` into 26 children alphabetically by the first letter for the record for the `name` column.  For example if I wanted all the records whose `name` starts with "A" from `parent_table_to_copy`, a subset is returned with:

```
dbname=> SELECT COUNT(id) FROM child_table_a;
count 
-------
34064
(1 row)
```

Now for the dump/restore into our backup of the database housed on **hostname2**
I used `--inserts` because of the *insert* trigger described above, didn't think the default`COPY` statement would work.

```
pg_dump --host=hostname1 --username=user --table="parent_table_to_copy" --inserts --data-only --file=dump_out.sql dbname
```

Contents of `dump_out.sql`  However there doesn't seem to be any `INSERT` commands.  If I take out `--inserts` then a `COPY` command appears.

```
--
-- PostgreSQL database dump
--

SET statement_timeout = 0;
SET lock_timeout = 0;
SET client_encoding = 'UTF8';
SET standard_conforming_strings = on;
SET check_function_bodies = false;
SET client_min_messages = warning;

SET search_path = public, pg_catalog;

--
-- Data for Name: parent_table_to_copy; Type: TABLE DATA; Schema: public; Owner: user
--


--
-- PostgreSQL database dump complete
--
```

Finally, `psql -U user -h hostname2 -d dbname -f dump_out.sql` just returns seven `SET` commands and when I `SELECT`  from **hostname2** there are 0 records.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated, thank you for reading. -Kevin

> Edit Below ~ Create table statement included

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS parent_table_to_copy
(
id INTEGER NOT NULL,
name CHARACTER VARYING(25) NOT NULL,
vartype CHARACTER VARYING(26) NOT NULL,
var2type NUMERIC NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE child_table_a
( CONSTRAINT child_table_a_id_fk FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES some_table (id) MATCH FULL ON DELETE CASCADE,
CONSTRAINT child_table_a_gene_name_fk FOREIGN KEY (name) REFERENCES some_other_table (name) MATCH FULL ON DELETE CASCADE,
CHECK (name like 'A%')
) INHERITS (parent_table_to_copy);
CREATE INDEX child_type_a ON child_table_a (id,name,vartype);
```

Comment: Is `parent_table_to_copy` an actual table? Would it not be a view that is just a `SELECT ... UNION` of the child tables?

Comment: @jcaron it is an actual table as far as I know; please see edit.  Column names are placeholders, not actual names.

Comment: So it uses the standard Postgresql partitioning with parent/child tables as described in the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/interactive/ddl-partitioning.html). The data is in the child tables, so just dump/restore the whole schema + the data for both the parent and child tables. The trigger is used so that clients don't need to know the details of the partitioning (they insert into the parent table, and the trigger dispatches to the child tables). Upon reading, the `CHECK` constraints do the dispatching automatically.

Comment: Thank you!  Saved me from pulling my hair out!
`pg_dump --host=hostname1 --username=user -t "child_table_*" --inserts --data-only --file=dump_out.sql dbname`

Comment: A regular copy should work as well, I don't think there's a specific need for inserts.

Comment: Will a regular copy insert correctly into a partitioned table? (Does it use insert triggers by default? )

Comment: I ended up using pg_dump w/o `--inserts` and it worked as jcaron suggested -- the tables partitioned correctly.   Unfamiliar with the default behavior of copy.