# postgres - move one part of partitioned table to new db as independent table

Tags: postgresql, restore

I have postgresql DB with partitioned table - can somebody help me understood how convert one part of this partitioned table to regular table in new DB?
When i search on google found information about partitioned :/ How proper ask google of operation which I want to perform?

Comment: Moving tables between databases means export/import.

Comment: I try pg_dump table_partitioned_part then restore in new DB - size is ok, but i cant access rows :/

Comment: I found answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34496006/postgresql-dump-and-restore-partitioned-table-w-insert-trigger-from-one-serve